# Flat table in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that returns two rows:

```
X   Y
20  0.148698
30  0.576208
```

I also have a function with following signature:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SomeFunc]
(
    @x1 float,
    @y1 float,
    @x2 float,
    @y2 float
)
```

What is the easiest way to pass params from this query in this function? Now i have a query, that declares four local variables and then I do four queries to fill all these variables and only then pass them into my function. But it seems that there is some better solution. For example I'm looking for something like:

```
WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT X1 = ..., Y1 = ..., X2 = ..., Y2 = ...
)
SELECT TOP 1 SomeFunc(X1, Y1, X2, Y2)
FROM CTE
```

This is why I called this question `Table flat`

---

Entire query is:

```
DECLARE @value float = 24;

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT X = CAST([name] AS float),
           Y = [rank]
    FROM [issdss].[dbo].[crit_scale]
    WHERE criteria_id = 128
),
CTE2 as (
    SELECT CTE.*, LeftDiff = IIF(X <= @value, @value - X, NULL), RightDiff = IIF(X >= @value, X - @value, NULL)
    FROM CTE
),
CTE3 as (
    SELECT X, Y
    FROM CTE2
    WHERE LeftDiff = (SELECT MIN(LeftDiff) FROM CTE2)
          OR RightDiff = (SELECT MIN(RightDiff) FROM CTE2)
),
-- Some magic here to get X1,Y1,X2,Y2
```

Comment: Does the order of the rows matter, i.e. must `X1`/`Y1` be `20`/`0.148698` or could that be `X2`/`Y2`? If it matters, how do you determine the order of the rows?

Comment: It just should be just two pairs, so it cannot be X1/Y2 and so on, but order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's always 2 rows, you can do something like this with row_number & max:

```
select 
  max(case when RN = 1 then X end) as X1,
  max(case when RN = 2 then X end) as X2,
  max(case when RN = 1 then Y end) as Y1,
  max(case when RN = 2 then Y end) as Y2
from (
  select row_number () over (order by (select null)) RN, *
  from (
    select 20 as X, 0.148698 as Y
    union all
    select 30, 0.576208
  ) X 
) Y
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/3146)

Comment: It's worth noting that the order in which the rows are processed in this solution is not guaranteed, lest anyone make that assumption. As Alex has clarified in a comment the order is not important for his question.

Comment: If specific order is needed that should be in the order by of row_number